# How can I define a function only knowing a few of its outputs and the output of its derivative when evaluated at a specific value?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I came across this problem in my calculus class, it's probably fairly easy but I've been scratching my head for hours:

$f(0) = 1; f(2) = 3; f ' (2) = 5$. Using integration, calculate:

$$
\int_0^2 xf''(x)dx
$$

Now, I know I'm not supposed to just copy and paste my textbook problems here, but I can't seem to find any way to figure out the original function to work with it and integrate what's asked. I apologize if this is ridiculous, just —please— enlighten me. I'm very confused.

Comment: Should the integral have specific bounds?  There are some _definite_ integrals of that form one can calculate, but the _indefinite_ integral is not determined by the information you've given.

Comment: Try $f$ to be of the form $f(x)=a+bx+cx^2$ and determine $a, b, c$ by your conditions  on $f$. But note that this is not the only function satisfying your conditions.

Comment: @JacobManaker man i feel so dumb, i copied the problem without the bounds... If you could help with this new info I'd greatly appreciate it, sorry to bother.

Comment: Integrate formally by parts and then use the given values, that's all.

Comment: @user376343 thanks bro, i was finally able to do it

Answer (score 2):

I am making the necessary and implicit assumption that $f:[0,2] \to \mathbb R$ is twice differentiable. In your title you speak about wanting to construct an $f$ to satisfy the three different equations required of it. I presume armed with such an $f$ you then wish to perform the integration to deduce the required numerical value. Whist this methodology will certainly yield the correct result if no mistakes are made in calculation, there is a much easier way to attack this question, and that is by using [integration by parts.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts), which I will give below. However, firstly and on a more pedagogical note, I will try to justify why trying to construct such an $f$ is not the best way to solve this question.

- Firstly, one is implicitly given a *specific* function $f$ which one needs to find an associated integral of. Ai priori, using any old $f$ that happens to to satisfy the three given equations does not *necessarily* mean that one will get the same value for the integral $\int_0^2 xf(x) \ \mathrm d x$. Of course one will, as the proof I give will demonstrate. But at this stages one cannot guarantee such thing is the case.
- Secondly you seem to believe that that one can reconstruct the function $f$ in its entirety from the data given to you. That is incorrect. In fact there are uncountably infinitely many twice differentiable functions $f$ that satisfy $f(0) = 1; f(2) = 3; f^\prime (2) = 5$. Showing this fact is beyond the scope of the question (but not too difficult in practise). You may like to try as an exercise to find two distinct functions satisfying the three equalities. Perhaps try polynomial functions if you would like.
- Lastly If a specific $f$ is not well chosen in such a way that is particularly hard to integrate, one may struggle hard with finding the correct value via integration. Thankfully as one of the commenters has pointed out, constructing a cubic function that satisfies the equalities is possible and moreover would lead to an approachable integral.

Now to answer the question proper. We will do so by observing a general result and then looking at a specific case to yield the desired result.

Suppose that $a, b \in \mathbb R$ are such that $a < b$ and $g,h$ are two twice differentiable real valued functions that are defined on the interval $[a,b]$. By twice using integration by parts observe equation $(1)$.

$$
\begin{align}
\int_a^b g(x) \cdot h^{\prime\prime}(x) \ \mathrm dx &= \left[g(x)\cdot h^{\prime}(x)\right]_a^b - \int_a^b g^\prime(x) \cdot h^{\prime}(x) \ \mathrm dx\\
&= \left[g(x)\cdot h^{\prime}(x)\right]_a^b - \left[g^\prime(x) \cdot h(x)\right]_a^b + \int_a^b g^{\prime\prime}(x) \cdot h(x) \ \mathrm dx 
\\ &= g(b)h^\prime(b) - g(a)h^\prime(a) - g^\prime(b)h(b) + g^\prime(a)h(a) + \int_a^b g^{\prime\prime}(x) \cdot h(x) \ \mathrm dx  
\tag{1}
\end{align} 
$$
Now, we turn again to the specifics of the posed problem. Suppose that $g$ is defined by $g(x) = x$ and that $h$ is given by the $f$ of the original question. Note that the first derivative of $g$ is identically $1$ and its second derivitive is identically $0$. This immediately implies that $\int_a^b g^{\prime\prime}(x) \cdot f(x) \ \mathrm dx = 0$  as it is the result of integrating a function that is constantly zero. In this light equation ($1$) reduces to identity $(2)$.
$$
\int_a^b xf^{\prime\prime}(x) \ \mathrm dx = b \cdot f^\prime(b) - a \cdot f^\prime(a) - f(b) + f(a). \tag{2}
$$
Furthermore, if $ a = 0$ and $b = 2$ then we receive that $\int_0^2 xf^{\prime\prime}(x) \ \mathrm dx = 2 \cdot f^\prime(2)  - f(2) + f(0)$. Then, in order to find the required value on needs only substitute the given values of $f$ and $f^\prime$.

Furthermore, one can build on this methodology to calculate integrals of the form  $\int_a^b P(x)h(x) \ \mathrm dx $ when only knowing the values $h^{(i)}(x)$ for $x \in \{a,b\}$ and $i \in \{0, \ldots, n\}$, where $n$ is the degree of a given polynomial function $P$. Showing This may be a good exercise for the one who posed the question.

Comment: It's borderline comedic on how serious you took what looks like a highschool exercise question, but still, amazing effort +1 from me

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simply use integration by parts to solve the problem. Actually, we will be treating the integral without limits initially, i.e indefinite integrals and after that we can just use the limits for the resultant function. I treat $x$ as the first function and $f''(x)$ as the second function.

$\displaystyle\int xf''(x)dx\\
=x\displaystyle\int f''(x)\,dx-\displaystyle\int \frac{d}{dx} (x) \left(\displaystyle\int f''(x)\,dx\right)dx= xf'(x)- \displaystyle\int f'(x)\,dx\\
= xf'(x)- f(x)$

Now $\displaystyle\int\limits_{0}^{2}xf''(x)\,dx= \left[xf'(x)- f(x)\right]_0^2= 2f'(2)-f(2)-0\cdot f'(0)+f(0)= 2\cdot 5-3+1= 8$